# BulkCreate in Sequelize but only update values if conditions are met

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, hook, bulkupdate

I need to bulk update in Sequelize, but I would like to update the value only if it is higher than the previous value.

Here's a simplified example table:

```
const HighestRecord = db.define('highestrecord', {
    atheleteId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    score: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
    },
})
```

The code below is just an imagining of how I would expect something like this to work in Sequelize. Is there something like this, or will I have to get each individual record and compare it first with a hook or loop? I'm importing several thousand rows each time and am worried about the performance.

```
HighestRecord.bulkCreate(todaysScores, {
    updateOnDuplicate: ['score'],
    where: { score: { [Op.gt]: Sequelize.col('highestrecords.score') } },
});
```